# Android SQLite database not saving data after app is closed

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

I was looking for some examples to learn how to use SQLite in android and found this: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/database/android-database-example/

I downloaded the project file and noticed that when I exit the app, if I have edited an entry or deleted one, it doesn't keep the changes afterwards. Shouldn't the database file just keep everything stored and up to date? What needs to be done to this code for it do so? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example project you are working from it has a function call in the `onCreate()` of the `Activity` that causes the table to be dropped each time the activity is opened:

```
// drop this database if already exists
db.onUpgrade(db.getWritableDatabase(), 1, 2);
```

The `onUpgrade()` function drops the table:

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    // drop books table if already exists
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS books");
    this.onCreate(db);
}
```